I am trying to install using pip install and keep getting errors
I'm having trouble installing the hvsrpy package using pip within my Anaconda environment. The installation fails with the following error:
    ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yoni\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 179, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  ...
  File "C:\Users\Yoni\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2m0vw2p2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from setuptools.extern.six import PY3, string_types
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools.extern.six'

Operating System: Windows 10
Python Version: 3.12.4 (via Anaconda Spyder)
Steps Taken:
Attempted to Install:
pip install hvsrpy 
This resulted in the error above.
Tried Upgrading pip and setuptools:
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

the upgrade was successful, but the hvsrpy installation still fails with the same error.
Checked for setuptools.extern.six:
I couldn't find the setuptools.extern.six module, which seems to be missing and causing the problem.
I couldn't find such a module - setuptools.extern.six.
I tried to install this hvsrpy package. it won't install. other pip installations did work. I also upgraded pip but didn't help.
Thanks in advance

Here are a few steps to troubleshoot and resolve this issue:
Firstly upgrade pip by running below command:
pip install --upgrade pip

Upgrade setup-tools:
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install six
pip cache purge (clear up the environment)

If upgrading doesn't help, try reinstalling setuptools.
pip uninstall setuptools
pip install setuptools

After trying these steps, attempt to run your script again.

Module 'setuptools.extern.six' was removed in 2020, Aug 16. setuptools version that corresponds to the date is 50.0.0. Try downgrading to an earlier version:
pip install -U "setuptools<50"


thanks, it solved the setuptools problem but now I get a new error:
'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils''

@YoniIsraeli https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ModuleNotFoundError%3A+No+module+named+%22distutils%27%27 Python 3.12 dropped distutils. IMO you're trying to install rather old package: hvsrpy 1.0.0 was released in 2021, see https://pypi.org/project/hvsrpy/1.0.0/ . Downgrade Python; try 3.11, 3.10, 3.9…
